# How to autocd in tcsh?

Tags: linux, cd-command, tcsh

I want to change directory without using cd, I want to access the directory by its name
$home/user/tools

```
$cd tools //works fine
$tools    //permission denied
```

I tried `set autocd` but still the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `tcsh`, this behaviour is turned on with `set implicitcd`, and not `set autocd`.